# How to do swatches for drupal commerce product variations

Tags: commerce, ajax

I am trying to add swatches to the product variations for drupal commerce. Ideally it would be a single image that changes based on the selection of something in a dropdown. If not that then maybe the image next to the title in the drop down. I looked into commerce fancy attributes module and it turns the drop down into a list of swatches which isn't exactly what I'm going for.

This sounds like something that could be done with ajax but I'm not sure how to do it.

If anyone knows how to do this some guidance would be much appreciated.